ufw blocking local IP coming from a wireguard tunnel
I tried to setup UFW to allow connection from a client that is connected via a wireguard tunnel with exit on another machine on the same LAN.
Let's call the machine that I want to access: server.
The client that need access from outside: client.
Exit point of the wireguard tunnel si the router: router.
I have a rules:
22    ALLOW IN    192.168.1.0/24      # Allow SSH from LAN (any client)  

This is working, if the client is physically on the same LAN, it's working.
Then the client connect from outside the LAN using the wireguard tunnel ending on the router. The client can access any other local machines on any port without issues.
The client gets another IP from the wireguard tunnel: 10.10.0.2, so I added this rule:
22     ALLOW IN    10.10.0.2          # Allow clcient to SSH from Wireguard tunnel

But it's not working.
I tried also 10.10.0.2/32 or 10.10.0.0/24 and even allow in ANYWHERE (as the port 22 is anyway not open to outside), but nothing works.
What am I missing? Is it a rules issue, or it's not related to UFW?

Reset everything
sudo ufw reset

Set Default Deny for Incoming, allow for outgoing, allow anything from 192.168.1.0/24 and 10.10.0.2 and enable ufw.
sudo ufw default deny incoming
sudo ufw default allow outgoing
sudo ufw allow from 192.168.1.0/24
sudo ufw allow from 10.10.0.2
sudo ufw enable

Take care after these commands only 192.168.1.0/24 and 10.10.0.2 has network access to this computer!
And check Status
sudo ufw status verbose

Output should look like this:
Status: active
To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
Anywhere                   ALLOW IN    192.168.1.0/24
Anywhere                   ALLOW IN    10.10.0.2

If you dont trust the source (10.10.0.2) completely and want to open just ssh port, then use this command:
sudo ufw allow from 10.10.0.2 to any port 22

